# How to post message from VSCode extension to custom webview created with WebviewProvider?

Tags: webview, vscode-extensions

I am building a VSCode extension where I create a custom tab in the panel with a Webview Provider. I want to direct the output of an extension command to Webview and render in html script. The alternative is to execute vscode extension command inside html script of the webview. However I could not find an example that uses Webview Provider, instead they all have
`currentPanel.webview.postMessage({ command: 'refactor' });`
which is undefined in my case because I do not create a panel.

extension.js

```
let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
"this is where I want to send data to webview"
...
);

var thisProvider={
    resolveWebviewView:function(thisWebview, thisWebviewContext, thisToke){
        thisWebview.webview.options={enableScripts:true}
        thisWebview.webview.html=`<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
            <div id="results" style="white-space: pre;" />
            <script>
            const resultsEl = document.getElementById("results");
            window.addEventListener('message', event => {

                const message = event.data; // The JSON data our extension sent
    
                switch (message.command) {
                    case 'results':
                        console.log(results);
                        break;
                }
            });
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>`;
    }
}

context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.window.registerWebviewViewProvider("monitor.output", thisProvider)
  );
```

package.json:

```
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
    {
        "command": "monitor.listen",
        "title": "Connect"
    }
    ],
    "menus": {
        "view/title": [
            {
                "command": "monitor.listen",
                "group": "navigation",
                "when": "view == monitor.output"
            }
        ]
    },
    "viewsContainers": {
      "panel": [
        {
          "id": "monitor",
          "title": "Monitor",
          "icon": "resources/monitor.jpeg"
        }
      ]
    },
    "views": {
      "monitor": [
        {
          "type": "webview",
          "id": "monitor.output",
          "name": "Monitor"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this too, but there is really no example showing how this could be added.

You can get and save the reference to the current `webView` inside `resolveWebView` function in your provider.

Store the view in a private instance variable `private _view?: vscode.WebviewView;` and use it in a public method `public postMessageToWebview(message: any)`

The provider code:

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

function getNonce() {
  let text = "";
  const possible =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
}

export class WebViewProvider
  implements vscode.WebviewViewProvider
{
  public static readonly viewType = 'myExtension.controlsView';

  private _view?: vscode.WebviewView;

  constructor(private readonly _extensionUri: vscode.Uri) {
  }

  public postMessageToWebview(message: any) {
    this._view?.webview.postMessage(message);
  }

  public resolveWebviewView(
    webviewView: vscode.WebviewView,
    context: vscode.WebviewViewResolveContext,
    _token: vscode.CancellationToken,
  ) {
    this._view = webviewView; // needed so we can use it in postMessageToWebview later

    webviewView.webview.options = {
      // Allow scripts in the webview
      enableScripts: true,

      localResourceRoots: [this._extensionUri],
    };

    webviewView.webview.html = this._getHtmlForWebview(
      webviewView.webview,
    );

    webviewView.webview.onDidReceiveMessage((data) => {
      switch (data.type) {
        // other message types ...
        case 'onYourEvent': {
          console.log(data.value); // see below webview to extension communication snippet
          break;
        }
        case 'onInfo': {
          if (!data.value) {
            return;
          }
          vscode.window.showInformationMessage(data.value);
          break;
        }
        case 'onError': {
          if (!data.value) {
            return;
          }
          vscode.window.showErrorMessage(data.value);
          break;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  private _getHtmlForWebview(webview: vscode.Webview) {
    // // And the uri we use to load this script in the webview
    const scriptUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
      vscode.Uri.joinPath(
        this._extensionUri,
        'out',
        'svelte-app/bundle.js',
      ),
    );
    // const scriptUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
    //   vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, "media", "main.js")
    // );

    // Local path to css styles
    const styleResetPath = vscode.Uri.joinPath(
      this._extensionUri,
      'media',
      'reset.css',
    );
    const stylesPathMainPath = vscode.Uri.joinPath(
      this._extensionUri,
      'media',
      'vscode.css',
    );

    // Uri to load styles into webview
    const stylesResetUri = webview.asWebviewUri(styleResetPath);
    const stylesMainUri = webview.asWebviewUri(stylesPathMainPath);
    const cssUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
      vscode.Uri.joinPath(
        this._extensionUri,
        'out/svelte-app',
        'bundle.css',
      ),
      // vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, "media", "main.css")
    );

    // Use a nonce to only allow specific scripts to be run
    const nonce = getNonce();

    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <!--
                    Use a content security policy to only allow loading images from https or from our extension directory,
                    and only allow scripts that have a specific nonce.
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src https: data:; style-src 'unsafe-inline' ${webview.cspSource}; script-src 'nonce-${nonce}';">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <link href="${stylesResetUri}" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="${stylesMainUri}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="${cssUri}" rel="stylesheet">
        <script nonce="${nonce}">
            const tsvscode = acquireVsCodeApi();
        </script>
            </head>
      <body>
            </body>
                <script nonce="${nonce}" src="${scriptUri}"></script>
            </html>`;
  }
}
```

**Note**:

- To get started remove the svelte bundle stuff (this was just part of my code base) and add a script file `media/main.js` with the code from the webview snippet below.
- The CSS files `reset.css` and `vscode.css` can be downloaded from a [VS Code example](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/webview-view-sample/media)
- To see your `console.log` messages you can open your dev. tools in your extension host VS code instance by hitting `ctrl+shif+p` and type `Open webview dev` - maybe you have to open/close your webview to generate new console logs.

You can use it in your `extension.ts`:

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import { WebViewProvider } from './WebViewProvider';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  const provider = new WebViewProvider(context.extensionUri);

  context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.commands.registerCommand('myExtension.sayHello', () => {
      // The code you place here will be executed every time your command is executed
      // Display a message box to the user
      // vscode.window.showInformationMessage(output);
      provider.postMessageToWebview({
        type: 'greeting',
        message: 'HelloWorld',
      });
    }),
  );

  context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.window.registerWebviewViewProvider(
      WebViewProvider.viewType,
      provider,
    ),
  );
}
```

Add it to the `package.json` so the command & view will be available:

```json
{
  "other-config": "...",
  "activationEvents": [
    "onView:myExtension.controlsView",
    "onCommand:myExtension.sayHello"
  ],
  "contributes": {
    "views": {
      "explorer": [
        {
          "type": "webview",
          "id": "myExtension.controlsView",
          "name": "MyExtension"
        }
      ],
    },
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "myExtension.sayHello",
        "category": "myExtension",
        "title": "SayHello"
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Webviews can be added at multiple locations in this code it will be added to the explorer view.

Use the following code in your webview script to get the message from the extension:

```js
// main.js code
const handleExtensionMessages = (event) => {
    const { message, type }= event.data;
    switch (message.type) {
        case 'greeting':
            console.log("received", message);
            break;
    }
}

window.addEventListener("message", handleExtensionMessages);
```

**For the other "direction" web view to extension communication.**

You can use in your webview content script:

```
tsvscode.postMessage({
    type: "onYourEvent",
    value: "anything you like to return",
  });
```

The global `tsvscode` variable is generated in `_getHtmlForWebview` with `acquireVsCodeApi()`.

To fix the typing for the global `tsvscode`. Install `@types/vscode-webview` with npm as `devDependency` and add a `global.d.ts` to your webview script with this content:

```js
import type WebViewApi from '@types/vscode-webview';

global {
  declare const tsvscode: WebViewApi<unknown>;
}
```

Or if you don't like the global variable `tsvscode` and the typing above. You could also create a VS Code API wrapper like in the following [repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-webview-ui-toolkit-samples/blob/main/frameworks/hello-world-svelte/webview-ui/src/utilities/vscode.ts).

Just to get this code running, create an extension as mentioned in the [Getting Started Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) with Yeoman generator by running `yo code` in your terminal.

You can also find the snippets in the following Github [gist](https://gist.github.com/AWolf81/c0fef6435487c989cd84811dd7973643).

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same problem. I wanted to register one of the `action buttons` in the top bar of a webview that shows up as a sidebar in the explore tab to refresh the content in my webview.

The solution above worked very well with one caveat: I needed to both handle the vscode->webview and webview->vscode interaction. What this means is, when I clicked my refresh button, an event is triggered to the webview that contains some data, excerpt shown below:

```
  extensionContext.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.commands.registerCommand(RESET_COMMAND, () => {
      provider.postMessageToWebview({
        type: "reset"
      });
    })
  );
```

This message, then needed to be handled by the webview, so for that I had to do the following inside a script in my webview provider:

```
    <script nonce=${nonce}>
      const tsvscode = acquireVsCodeApi();

      window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
        const message = event.data;
        switch (message.type) {
            case 'reset':
                tsvscode.postMessage({ type:"reset" });
                break;
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Now, tsvscode can reach out to my webview event listener by posting the message, which handles it inside the `resolveWebviewView` function as follows:

```
   webviewView.webview.onDidReceiveMessage((data) => {
      switch (data.type) {
        case "reset":
          webviewView.webview.html = this.getHtmlContent(
            webviewView.webview,
            "<div>reset page!</div>" // this is just rendering some new content in the page when it is reset
          );
          break;
        default: {
          break;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

which *finally* resets the page!

What I have describes implements both directions of communication vscode->webview and webview->vscode. You might be wondering, why couldn't you just post the message on the webview and then handle it with the onDidRecieve on the same webview? I am wondering the same thing, that doesn't seem to have the proper event listener registered to work directly, which is why this workaround where we add `addEventListener` seems to work instead.

I hope this helps!